# Advanced queue module: How to stop processing queue in cron, when some conditions apply in job event/job preprocessing?

Tags: cron

I have a custom module handling jobs from the [Advanced Queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/advancedqueue) module.
To limit the number of jobs allowed to be processed in one cron run, I have some configuration variables in my custom module. With an event listener my function gets called correctly, when the queue is processed.

How can I fetch the current running process of the queue and stop it?

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
  $events[AdvancedQueueEvents::PRE_PROCESS][] = ['checkLimits'];
  return $events;
}

public function checkLimits(JobEvent $event) {
  $job_type = $event->getJob()->getType();
  if ($job_type === 'MYMODULE_send_reports') {
    $config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('MYMODULE.settings');
    if (!empty($config)) {
      $number_of_max_emails_to_send_per_day  = $config->get('number_of_max_emails_to_send_per_day');
      $number_of_max_emails_to_send_per_hour = $config->get('number_of_max_emails_to_send_per_hour');
      $remaining_emails_day = $config->get('remaining_emails_day');
      $remaining_emails_hour = $config->get('remaining_emails_hour');

      if ($remaining_emails_day <= 0) {
        $queue = Queue::load($event->getJob()->getQueueId());

        // $processor_id is only a string like "cron".
        $processor_id = $queue->getProcessor();

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like an open feature request: https://www.drupal.org/project/advancedqueue/issues/3174373